# Why is my wordpress page's content not visible?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on my portfolio website. I just finished working on all the HTML CSS JavaScript and now I want to convert my website to WordPress. So I create my custom theme, create my pages and templates, rename all my .html files to .php and upload evrythin on my server. However, when I go to my site, the content is there (you can see it in the page inspector), but it is invisible for some reason. Only the header (header.php) is visible. I tried reinstalling WordPress on my server, nothing changed. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks! Here is the link: [problematic website](https://felixpoirier.ca/)

Comment: log in to admin and add your page content there, so that wordpress can load the content by your pages

Comment: Yes I will do  that in the future, but right now I'm just trying to see my HTML content before making it dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some console errors that need to be fixed:

[image]

Additionally there is CSS hiding the content:

[image]

Removing the `opacity: 0` reveals the content:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a stupid mistake on my part... Forgot to add <?php bloginfo('template_url') ?> on my script.js...

Comment: Nice, happy to hear you got it working.  Site looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Dang, @mikerojas, you beat me to it. ;)

Just to add a little bit: In the page source you'll see `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` near the top. It seems the browser looks for the script at https://felixpoirier.ca/js/script.js, and doesn't find it.

You might start out by looking up wp_enqueue_script and see how to solve the problem the WordPress way. Or you could for now double-check the code that's adding the bad link for typos or other mistakes.

You also might at least partially solve the problem by going to themes/customizer/Additional CSS - if they're working for your theme in its current form - and add something like `.elementAnimer { opacity: 1 !important }` Alternatively, you could just remove the elementAnimer class from the sections it's currently being applied to - the first section and the third. You might then at least get readable output, if not fully animated output as intended.

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot to add <?php bloginfo('template_url') ?> in front of my script.js which was preventing the rest of the page from loading!

Comment: Good call on the `wp_enqueue_script`.